# How to define the path in PHP using include or best practices

Tags: php

HI all

i am working on my brother site where he got "BreadCrumbs.php" on "publich_html" where index.html there also.

in public_html , i have few folder like "About Us", "career" and html file are in there as well. Now when i am putting "BreadCrumbs.php" link to Index.html file, it show the result, but when i am putting the same link to (i.e. about us.html which is in 'About us" Folder, its not working.

i am just wondering how i should define the include path so it works with the Folder as well.
like this ...

Public_html
  |
  |__ index.html
  |__ BreadCrumbs.php
  |__ About Us > aboutus.html  **(File is in the Folder)**
  |
  |__ Career > career.html **(File is in the Folder)**

little help is really appriciate.

to add to my post i ahve this code

```
include_once('class.breadcrumb.inc.php');  
$breadcrumb = new breadcrumb;
echo "<p>".$breadcrumb->show_breadcrumb()."</p>";
```

its only work with index.html file. Not for other file which is are in the folders

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to overcome the problem:

```
$about = HTTP_SERVER . 'folder/about.html';
```

The `HTTP_SERVER` will transform your link from `about.html` to `http://www.yourhost.com/about.html`

Note: Unless you are using Mod Rewrite to transform a php extension to html then you will need to have PHP code in only pages with the php extension (*.php).

Comment: can you explain a little how and where i should be putting this above line...because i have this fro my cell which is not working  <?php
 include_once('class.breadcrumb.inc.php');
 $breadcrumb = new breadcrumb;
 echo "<p>".$breadcrumb->show_breadcrumb()."</p>";
?>  whi is only workign for index.html file not for about us file which is in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the directory structure and include from a deeper level.

In public_html: `include("./class.breadcrumb.inc.php");`

In the subfolders: `include("../class.breadcrumb.inc.php");`

Hope this helps!